# Where/how is the smart contract webassembly binary stored in NEAR protocol?

Tags: nearprotocol

How can you extract the smart contract WebAssembly binaries by exploring the NEAR protocol blockchain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
http --json post https://rpc.mainnet.near.org jsonrpc=2.0 id=dontcare method=query \
params:='{"request_type":"view_code","finality":"final","account_id":"contract.near"}' \
| jq -r .result.code_base64 \
| base64 --decode > contract.wasm
```

Answer (score 3):

Near has an account-based model similar to Ethereum. However, I don't think we have currently exposed downloading the Wasm binary through RPC. Added https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/issues/1712